# Error when trying to alter an existing stored procedure with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I follow this MSDN article to alter an existing stored procedure with PowerShell:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162190.aspx
(*No need to read that*)

Inside this example the following line throws an error:

```
$sp = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.StoredProcedure -argumentlist $db, "GetUserPhoneForService"
```

The error is

> New-Object : The type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.StoredProcedure] cannot be found. Be sure you loaded the assembly containing this type.

(I translated the error message from German. So the wording might be a bit different)

Other database actions like simple updates work without any problem.

Comment: My first guess is that you didn't start powershell from SQL Management Studio (right click on server and select "Start Powershell") and therefore don't have the SQL module imported into the shell. Is that the case?

Comment: That is right. But I did not have to start from Management studio when updating data, either (using system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand). I am trying to write a script for my admin collegues to run directly from shell.

Comment: See @vonPryz answer for the way to import the module you need. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` is something in the default .NET Framework, where the SMO objects are only there if Management Studio is installed in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the Sql Powershell provider. Use `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to see all the offered modules. Load the sqlps with `Import-Module` like so,

```
import-module sqlps
```